# Are there diffrent understandings of dimensions?

Tags: spacetime-dimensions, degrees-of-freedom

If people are talking about 4 or higher dimensions they are always pictured as space dimensions. But if you have have a look at the simplest definition of a mathematical dimension it only needs to be linear independent. Therefore mass, charge, spin, etc. all fulfill the meaning to be a dimension.

Therefore my question: If you look at a classical environment wouldn't you already need 6 dimensions  (mass, time, 3x space dimensions, charge) to describe it and even more if your moving to quantum mechanics? Why are people than saying that we only live in 3 dimensions, if you can't describe anything in it?

Comment: As you said we certainly live in 3 SPATIAL dimensions. And using only these 3 spatial dimensions and time we can describe phenomena involving a set of physical properties likes mass, charge, electric/magnetic moment, current, refraction index, etc.

Comment: The "simplest" dimension is that of a [topological space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_covering_dimension). Mass, charge, spin, etc. may be *parameters*, but you would have to say what the space is you are considering them as inducing dimensions on.

Comment: But what is the maning if theory states that it needs 200 or more dimensions? Are these only spatial ones, because otherwise I wouldn't find it hard to imagine.

Comment: Charge is quantized so it would be quite odd to think of it as a dimension compared to others that appear to be continuous.

Comment: But than it would also be strange to think about one of the spin dimensions and space as a dimension. @AcuriousMind and what about the Pauli Matrixes in a SU(2)?

Comment: What about them?

Comment: Dimensions are what are used to define the geometry/topology of the universe. We currently can define the geometry/topology of our universe using 4 dimensions. The other values are parameters, constants, relations, etc. Anything that is a dimension can be given its own term in the metric. Mass and charge may affect the geometry, but they don't describe the geometry